# Sending Data over network inside kernel

Tags: linux, network-programming, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a driver in Linux kernel that sends data over the network . Now suppose that my data to be sent  (buffer) is in kernel space . how do i send the data without creating a socket (First of all is that a good idea at all ? ) .I'm looking for performance in the code rather than easy coding . And how do i design the receiver end ? without a socket connection , can i get and view the data on the receiver end (How) ? And will all this change ( including the performance) if the buffer is in user space (i'll do a copy from user if it does :-) ) ?

Comment: What kind of device is it? What kind of network?

Comment: well i wanted to implement a generic driver working for all net devices . Well i've read far too many articles forbidding me to write networking code inside kernel space . Wanted see wat happens if i do so

Comment: I came across a new thought today . Would it make sense if i make a socket descriptor in userspace and pass it during module insertion of my driver and use it until it's unloaded > it'll still help me save the time for  context switches . Just a random thought Need to know if this's any better than my original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to send data on the network without sockets you'd need to hook into the network drivers and send raw packets through them and filter their incoming packets for those you want to hijack. I don't think the performance benefit will be large enough to warrant this.

I don't even think there are normal hooks for this in the network drivers, I did something relevant in the past to implement a firewall. You could conceivably use the netfilter hooks to do something similar in order to attach to the receive side from the network drivers.

Comment: Hmmm . Well now i'm starting to dislike the idea of sending data over network from inside the kernel . may be i could create a one time socket descriptor and pass it on to the kernel and use it perpetually . See comments i've written above

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [netlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink), and if you want to really communicate with a distant host (e.g. thru TCP/IPv6) use a user-level proxy application for that. (so kernel module use netlink to your application proxy, which could use TCP, or even go thru `ssh` or HTTP, to send the data remotely, or store it on-disk...).

I don't think that having a kernel module directly talking to a distant host makes sense otherwise (e.g. security issues, filtering, routing, `iptables` ...)

And the real bottleneck is almost always the (physical) network itself. a 1Gbit ethernet is almost always much slower than what a kernel module, or an application, can sustainably produce (and also latency issues).

Comment: Netlink ? I'm not creating a user-space application to support this device . The whole device sits on kernel space .